# Convert string of whitespace separated numbers in a string into integers and place them in variables

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function(s) to accept a string of 4 whitespace separated numbers in a string, separate and convert them to integers, and place them in 4 individual integer variables.  I know I can use `splitWs` to split them into a string array, use `!!` to access the individual elements, and something like the following to convert to integer:

```
f :: [String] -> [Int]
f = map read
```

But I can't figure out how to put it all together.

Answer (score 15):

Use the [`words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3awords) function to split the string by whitespace.  Then you can `map read` over the result.

Thus, a simple implementation would be:

```
readNumbers :: String -> [Int]
readNumbers = map read . words
```

Then, if you need exactly four numbers, use pattern matching:

```
case readNumbers string of
    [a,b,c,d] -> ...
    _         -> error "Expected four numbers"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no variables in Haskell, in Haskell strings are represented as lists. So

try:

```
import Data.List.Utils
nums=map read $split " " "1 2 3 4" :: [Int]
```

You can access the single elements with (!!):

```
> nums(!!)0
1
```

HTH Chris

Comment: why not use `splitWs` instead of `split " "`?

Comment: Why not use [`words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3awords) instead of either?

Comment: `!!` is inefficient compared to pattern matching because of 4 list traversals vs 1